# "-bash: ./ngrok: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: ubuntu, ngrok

I am facing this error when connecting ngrok to Blackeye operation in Ubuntu 20.04. This is when I input authentication token in the format "./ngrok authtoken *******" as provided in the ngrok website. Please assist. Note that I am an amateur user of Ubuntu..

Comment: What is the result of `file ngrok`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you downloaded the wrong ngrok TGZ file for your CPU architecture. ngrok supports x86, ARM, MIPS, and a few mainframe architectures. If you go to https://ngrok.com/download and select `Linux` you'll see a dropdown. Make sure you select the one that correlates to your computer's CPU. Alternatively, you can also install via `Apt` or `Snap`. The commands for both are on the download page linked above.

Comment: yes, although there is option for Linux, we need to check whether the linux is ARM, ARM64, or Linux(32Bit). I also faced the same issue.